# Get url parameter with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I try to get a URL parameter `nr`, but I get always `false`.

```
var url = window.location.href;
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let nr = params.has('nr')
```

What is the error?

Comment: what is the URL you're parsing?

Comment: Please share the `window.location.href`

Comment: btw `.has()` will return you a boolean not the parameter. You need to use `get()` to get the parameter. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Hello,
here http://xxxxx/cocktail?nr=1

Comment: you can omit the real host if you want to keep that private, the important parts are after the host

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
var url = window.location;
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let nr = params.has('nr')
```

because window.location is a Location object with a `.search` property

whereas window.location.href is a string, without a `.search` property

therefore your `url.search` is `undefined`

I can demonstrate with `URL` which is similar to `Location` in this respect

```js
let loc = new URL('http://example.com/?nr=1');

// loc is a placeholder for your window.location

let url = loc.href;

// here, url.search would be window.location.href.search
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let nr = params.has('nr')
console.log(nr);

url = loc;

// here, url.search would be window.location.search
params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
nr = params.has('nr')
console.log(nr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The below function will return Array of all parameters from url

```js
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }
  
  var params = getUrlVars();
  
  console.log(params["nr"]);
```

reference taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097994/8077687

Comment: A good answer only if you need to support Internet Explorer

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

`The URLSearchParams constructor does not parse full URLs. However, it will strip an initial leading ? off of a string, if present.`

So you should only provide the query params string.

e.g. if your window.location.href is

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314446/get-url-parameter-with-javascript?query=1&query_1=2&many_queries=3
```

Then you should pass the URLSearchParams class only the query params, viz
`query=1&query_1=2&many_queries=3`